# Bixby: Audio player concept

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am showing artist to user and following up by asking if user wanted to listen the song of this artist.

**Endpoint**

```
action-endpoint (PlayArtist) {
  accepted-inputs (artist_id)   // here too yellow line (Missing required input `artistToPlay`)
  local-endpoint (PlayArtist.js)
}
action-endpoint (BuildArtistAudioInfo) {
  accepted-inputs (artist_id)
  local-endpoint (BuildArtistAudioInfo.js)
}
```

**BuildArtistAudioInfo.model.bxb**

```
action (BuildArtistAudioInfo) {
  type (Search)
  description (Makes a meow info to play.)
  collect{
    input (artist_id){
      type (ArtistID)
      min (Optional)
      max (One)
    }
  }
  output (audioPlayer.AudioInfo)
}
```

**Follow-up**

```
followup {
  prompt {
    dialog (Would you like to play music for this artist)
      on-confirm {
        if (false) {
          message (I see...)
        } else {
          intent {
            goal: PlayArtist
            value: $expr(singleArtistEvent.artistId)
          }
      }
   }
   on-deny {
      message (OK friend.)
   }
 }
}
```

Now i need to pass this value to PlayArtist action file but after seeing your sample capsule i am confused where to pass the input.

**PlayArtist Action file**

```
action (PlayArtist) {
  type (Search)
  collect {
     input (artist_id){
       type (ArtistID)
       min (Optional)
       max (One)
     }
     computed-input (artistToPlay) {
        description (Create the playlist to play)
        type (audioPlayer.AudioInfo)
        min (Required) max (One)
        compute {
           intent {
             goal: BuildArtistAudioInfo
             value:ArtistID(artist_id) // i am confused over here, it's giving error ()
           }
        }
        //hidden     
     }

     computed-input (play) {
         description (By passing in the AudioInfo object to the PlayAudio action, we ask the client to play our sound.)
         type (audioPlayer.Result)
         compute {
            intent {
              goal: audioPlayer.PlayAudio
              value: $expr(artistToPlay)
            }
         }
         //hidden
      }
  }
  output (Result)
}
```

Do i need to extra `accept-input`? also `BuildArtistAudioInfo.js` file has songs info, so i need to get the artist id here and proceed it to the api where I will get song info. please guide.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need an input artistID in action model PlayArtist and action model BuildArtistAudioInfo, that's how the artistID pass to BuildArtistAudioInfo.js as an argument
2. In `computed-input (artistToPlay)`, intent block should have a value field
3. Use `value` in intent instead of `value-set`, since it's single value, not a set
4. Make sure in endpoints.bxb you correctly link JS file to action model, that is accepted input and argument name must match.

Comment: Why do I need input artistID in both action, isn't it enough to pass to BuildArtistAudioInfo action so that I can pass it to the js?

Comment: (artistID) --> follow-up --> PlayArtist --> BuildArtistAudioInfo. The value you set in follow-up cannot get to BuildArtistAudioInfo directly.

Comment: Have updated my question as per the instruction, but something is still not working.

Comment: If you comment out `hidden`, then that input must be an argument of linked JS function, for the error, try $expr(artist_id)